# Histoire des pluriels irréguliers

Tags: étymologie, pluriel, latin, ancien-français

Etymologiquement, d'où viennent les pluriels des noms en "al" (et ails) qui font "aux" en français?

Du latin (par exemple *animalia* est un pluriel irrégulier)?
Quand cette règle a-t-elle commencé à s'appliquer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

/o/ est l'évolution régulière des séquences -al et en -ail /aʎ/ suivies d'une consonne en ancien français. Par example le latin salvum /'sal.wum/ donne en latin vulgaire /sal.βʊ/, en proto-français /salf/ et finalement /saʊ̬f/, d'où l'orthographe du mot, sauf, en français moderne.

Ce dernier changement, de la consonne /l/ à la voyelle /ʊ̯/ est généralement daté du dixième siècle et ne s'est pas produit uniquement à l'intérieur d'une racine, mais aussi devant des suffixes, comme le -t de la troisième personne (valt > vaut) et le -s du pluriel.

On passe donc de mal/mals à mal/maus, dont le /s/ final vient conventionnellement à s'orthographier x à partir du treizième siècle.

La prononciation moderne est atteinte au seizième siècle avec la réduction de la diphtongue /aʊ̬/ en /o/ et la perte des consonnes finales. Maux se prononce donc depuis /mo(:)(z)/.

Beaucoup de ces mots à pluriel irrégulier ont depuis été régularisés sur le modèle d'une de leur formes: ail/aulx est passé à ail/ails; matérial/matériaux est passé à matériau/matériaux.

Quant à animal, il s'agit d'un emprunt au latin plutôt que d'un mot qui ait évolué régulièrement en français. Comme l'emprunt s'est fait à une époque où le changement de -als en -aus était encore actif (au douzième siècle), il a acquis naturellement un pluriel en -aus. Ce n'est plus le cas des emprunts récents, on parle d'aliments halals et pas d'aliments halaux par exemple.

Un mot descendu directement d'animalia a existé en français mais il est sorti de l'usage: aumaille, au pluriel aumailles.